# Linear Layout OnClick Listener not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Hi i have LinearLayout with horizontal orientation has two childrens as follows

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/clearAll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/clear_all_bg"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close_white" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_micro"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

At run time i have set OnClickListner for LinearLayout like this

```
clearAll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.clearAll);
    clearAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, "clearAll Click");
        }
    });
```

I tried with

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

and

```
android:clickable="true"
```

but no use listener is not triggered

Comment: try increase padding of the linear layout,then try

Comment: are you putting the code for onClickListener in onCreate() or some other method?

Comment: try click event on Imgeview and Textview because your LinearLayout covered with these two so you are not getting click event .

Comment: Give a `android:padding="50dp"` or more to your `Linear Layout` it will work.

Answer (score 1):

> it may be click to textview or imageview
>
> Method 1: Try to take  android:focusableInTouchMode="false" to textview and imageview

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/clearAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/clear_all_bg"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close_white" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_micro"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

> Method 2: Or set id to image view and Textview and try this...

```
 textview.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: *"it may be click to textview or imageview"*...Why? Shouldn't parent ViewGroup be the deciding entity for click events?